# Display data into textbox in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

I am new to codeigniter. I am stuck somewhere in displaying the value retrieved from database!
How can I display the value extracted from Database into the Textbox using Codeigniter ?

My view is : PutArtistProfile_v

```
<?php 
 foreach ($return_Name as $row ) 
    {
        echo '<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />';
    }
?>
```

My Controller is:

```
public function index($return_Name)
{       
    $this->load->view('PutArtistProfile_v', $return_Name );
}
```

$return_Name -- have data fetched from database.

Comment: I am getting the value into the controller from Model in my MVC. But I am not able to display the content into the textbox.

Comment: please post some code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach($return_Name as $key)
{
    $val= $key->text_name;
    echo "<input type='text' value='$val' />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In View -

```
<?php 
     foreach ($return_Name as $row ) 
        {
            echo '<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" value="$row->columnname" />';
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to send your result to view:

In controller:

```
public function index($return_Name)
{       
    $data['return_Name'] = $return_Name;
    $this->load->view('PutArtistProfile_v', $data );
}
```

In view you can get data like `$return_Name`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data to view using controller method

```
public function index()
{       
    $data['return_data'] = $this->model_name->function_name();
    $this->load->view('view_filename', $data );
}
```

And in view you can access the value using loop

```
foreach($return_data as $row)
{
    echo '<input type="text" name="name" value="$row['column_name']" /';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access your data from session variables from controller

```
$data['id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
```

And in view you can echo it out in input fields

```
<input type="text" name="id_admin" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"   maxlength="50" class="form-control" />
```